# Is there a way to update the same file which is getting read for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, optimization, time

I have a while loop that is reading a file line by line. Based on some conditions, I want to delete a few lines of the same file to reduce the loop time(As the file has millions of lines).
Is there a possible way?
Below is the code example:

```
while read -r line
do
<Processing>
sed -i "/<pattern>/d" $file
done < "$file"
```

when I run the above code, it is not deleting the lines in run time. I can see the updated $file only after the loop ends(which is not reducing the loop time).

Comment: Is this even possible in any other language?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that something like the following will happen:

1. Bash opens a file pointer to the *inode* currently referenced by `$file`.
2. `read` reads up to the first newline of the *file pointer.*
3. `sed` reads the inode currently referenced by `$file`, creates a *new file* with the *same path but a different inode* containing copies of some of the lines from the original file.
4. Repeat from 2.

Basically, this does *not* do in-place replacement, since `read` keeps reading from one inode and `sed` keeps creating new inodes with the same path containing new content.

A faster solution would be to build up a `sed` *script* containing all the replacements, and running that *once* after the loop. The script would look something like this:

```
/foo/d
/bar/d
…
```

or this:

```
/foo\|bar\|…/d
```

Comment: I think you are right. Due to the actions `sed` is doing, it can not possibly replace the file in-place. This would need a file with a fixed record structure. I wonder what semantics the OP wants to achieve with this program, when he changes with _sed_  the very same file he is about to process in a loop ....

Comment: Thanks for looking into the problem. I know it's a little weird to update the same loop file in run time. I would clear my intent. I have to process each line of a file having a million lines. Let's take an example, having A B C D in line number 1. Getting line number 1 input, we figured out that there is no requirement to process those lines which contain A. Can we do something to not even look at those lines containing 'A' in the same file, so that it saves run time.